# Visual Studio Bugs after Windows Update - example Manage User Secrets disappeared

Tags: c#, .net, windows, visual-studio

Windows installed updates, my Windows became Windows 11, however I am facing several problems with Visual Studio, when Visual Studios Starts two errors messages are displayed on the top, additionally Manage User Secrets disappeared from the context menu.

Any suggestion? For the time being I will take the risk to add my connection string in Application Settings.

[image]

You can find below one of the error log :

## '''

05/12/2021 10:25:45
Recoverable
System.AggregateException: Project system data flow 'DataflowBlockSlim (ActionBlockSlimAsync`1 : 61833216)' closed because of an exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: An attempt was made to import a component of type 'Microsoft.WebTools.Shared.VS.Contracts.IBrowserLaunchService' from the global scope, but no such export could be found. at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Containers.Tools.Common.ScopedExports.GetExportsForParameter(ParameterInfo parameter, IScopedExportsContext context) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Containers.Tools.Common.ScopedExports.<>c__DisplayClass14_0`1.b__3(ParameterInfo parameter)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext() at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source) at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Containers.Tools.Common.ScopedExports.CreateImplementationTypeFromContext[TExportedType](IScopedExportsContext context, Type implementationType)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Containers.Tools.Common.ScopedExports.<>c__DisplayClass10_0`1.<RegisterAttributedExport>b__0(IScopedExportsContext context) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Containers.Tools.Common.ScopedExports.<>c__DisplayClass9_0`1.b__1()
at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue() at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
at System.Lazy`1.get_Value() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Containers.Tools.Common.CommonScopedExports.get_BrowserServiceExport() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Containers.Tools.Package.Exports.get_BrowserService() --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] index, CultureInfo culture) at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue(Object obj, Object[] index) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.GetValueFromMember(Object exportingPart, MemberInfo exportingMember, Type importingSiteElementType, Type exportedValueType) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.<>c__DisplayClass15_0.<GetExportedValueHelper>b__0() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.GetValueForImportElement(RuntimePartLifecycleTracker importingPartTracker, RuntimeImport import, RuntimeExport export, Func`3 lazyFactory)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.GetValueForImportSite(RuntimePartLifecycleTracker importingPartTracker, RuntimeImport import)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.RuntimePartLifecycleTracker.b__11_0(RuntimeImport import)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext() at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source) at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.RuntimePartLifecycleTracker.CreateValue()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.Create()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.MoveNext(PartLifecycleState nextState)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.MoveToState(PartLifecycleState requiredState)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.GetValueReadyToExpose()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.<>c__DisplayClass15_0.b__0()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.DelegateServices.<>c__DisplayClass2_0`1.<As>b__0() at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue() at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Debug.LaunchProfilesDebugLaunchProvider.GetLaunchTargetsProvider(ILaunchProfile profile)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Debug.LaunchProfilesDebugLaunchProvider.d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Debug.StartupProjectRegistrar.d__14.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Debug.StartupProjectRegistrar.<b__13_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.CommonProjectSystemTools.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.DataReceivingBlockSlim`1.<ProcessInputQueueAsync>d__5.MoveNext() --- End of inner exception stack trace --- ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: An attempt was made to import a component of type 'Microsoft.WebTools.Shared.VS.Contracts.IBrowserLaunchService' from the global scope, but no such export could be found. at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Containers.Tools.Common.ScopedExports.GetExportsForParameter(ParameterInfo parameter, IScopedExportsContext context) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Containers.Tools.Common.ScopedExports.<>c__DisplayClass14_0`1.b__3(ParameterInfo parameter)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext() at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source) at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Containers.Tools.Common.ScopedExports.CreateImplementationTypeFromContext[TExportedType](IScopedExportsContext context, Type implementationType)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Containers.Tools.Common.ScopedExports.<>c__DisplayClass10_0`1.<RegisterAttributedExport>b__0(IScopedExportsContext context) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Containers.Tools.Common.ScopedExports.<>c__DisplayClass9_0`1.b__1()
at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue() at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
at System.Lazy`1.get_Value() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Containers.Tools.Common.CommonScopedExports.get_BrowserServiceExport() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Containers.Tools.Package.Exports.get_BrowserService() --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] index, CultureInfo culture) at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue(Object obj, Object[] index) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.GetValueFromMember(Object exportingPart, MemberInfo exportingMember, Type importingSiteElementType, Type exportedValueType) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.<>c__DisplayClass15_0.<GetExportedValueHelper>b__0() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.GetValueForImportElement(RuntimePartLifecycleTracker importingPartTracker, RuntimeImport import, RuntimeExport export, Func`3 lazyFactory)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.GetValueForImportSite(RuntimePartLifecycleTracker importingPartTracker, RuntimeImport import)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.RuntimePartLifecycleTracker.b__11_0(RuntimeImport import)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext() at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source) at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.RuntimePartLifecycleTracker.CreateValue()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.Create()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.MoveNext(PartLifecycleState nextState)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.MoveToState(PartLifecycleState requiredState)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.GetValueReadyToExpose()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.<>c__DisplayClass15_0.b__0()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.DelegateServices.<>c__DisplayClass2_0`1.<As>b__0() at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue() at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Debug.LaunchProfilesDebugLaunchProvider.GetLaunchTargetsProvider(ILaunchProfile profile)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Debug.LaunchProfilesDebugLaunchProvider.d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Debug.StartupProjectRegistrar.d__14.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Debug.StartupProjectRegistrar.<b__13_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.CommonProjectSystemTools.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.DataReceivingBlockSlim`1.<ProcessInputQueueAsync>d__5.MoveNext()<--- . ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: An attempt was made to import a component of type 'Microsoft.WebTools.Shared.VS.Contracts.IBrowserLaunchService' from the global scope, but no such export could be found. at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Containers.Tools.Common.ScopedExports.GetExportsForParameter(ParameterInfo parameter, IScopedExportsContext context) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Containers.Tools.Common.ScopedExports.<>c__DisplayClass14_0`1.b__3(ParameterInfo parameter)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext() at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source) at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Containers.Tools.Common.ScopedExports.CreateImplementationTypeFromContext[TExportedType](IScopedExportsContext context, Type implementationType)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Containers.Tools.Common.ScopedExports.<>c__DisplayClass10_0`1.<RegisterAttributedExport>b__0(IScopedExportsContext context) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Containers.Tools.Common.ScopedExports.<>c__DisplayClass9_0`1.b__1()
at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue() at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
at System.Lazy`1.get_Value() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Containers.Tools.Common.CommonScopedExports.get_BrowserServiceExport() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Containers.Tools.Package.Exports.get_BrowserService() --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] index, CultureInfo culture) at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue(Object obj, Object[] index) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.GetValueFromMember(Object exportingPart, MemberInfo exportingMember, Type importingSiteElementType, Type exportedValueType) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.<>c__DisplayClass15_0.<GetExportedValueHelper>b__0() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.GetValueForImportElement(RuntimePartLifecycleTracker importingPartTracker, RuntimeImport import, RuntimeExport export, Func`3 lazyFactory)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.GetValueForImportSite(RuntimePartLifecycleTracker importingPartTracker, RuntimeImport import)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.RuntimePartLifecycleTracker.b__11_0(RuntimeImport import)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext() at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source) at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.RuntimePartLifecycleTracker.CreateValue()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.Create()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.MoveNext(PartLifecycleState nextState)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.MoveToState(PartLifecycleState requiredState)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.GetValueReadyToExpose()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.<>c__DisplayClass15_0.b__0()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.DelegateServices.<>c__DisplayClass2_0`1.<As>b__0() at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue() at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Debug.LaunchProfilesDebugLaunchProvider.GetLaunchTargetsProvider(ILaunchProfile profile)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Debug.LaunchProfilesDebugLaunchProvider.d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Debug.StartupProjectRegistrar.d__14.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Debug.StartupProjectRegistrar.<b__13_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.CommonProjectSystemTools.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.DataReceivingBlockSlim`1.<ProcessInputQueueAsync>d__5.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.CommonProjectSystemTools.Rethrow(Exception ex) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ProjectErrorReporting.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<SubmitErrorReport>b__0() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ExceptionFilter.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Guard>g__Action|0() at GuardMethodClass.GuardMethod(Func`1 , Func`2 , Func`2 )
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: An attempt was made to import a component of type 'Microsoft.WebTools.Shared.VS.Contracts.IBrowserLaunchService' from the global scope, but no such export could be found.
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Containers.Tools.Common.ScopedExports.GetExportsForParameter(ParameterInfo parameter, IScopedExportsContext context)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Containers.Tools.Common.ScopedExports.<>c__DisplayClass14_0`1.<CreateImplementationTypeFromContext>b__3(ParameterInfo parameter) at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Containers.Tools.Common.ScopedExports.CreateImplementationTypeFromContext[TExportedType](IScopedExportsContext context, Type implementationType) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Containers.Tools.Common.ScopedExports.<>c__DisplayClass10_0`1.b__0(IScopedExportsContext context)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Containers.Tools.Common.ScopedExports.<>c__DisplayClass9_0`1.<RegisterExport>b__1() at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue() at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Containers.Tools.Common.CommonScopedExports.get_BrowserServiceExport()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Containers.Tools.Package.Exports.get_BrowserService()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] index, CultureInfo culture)
at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue(Object obj, Object[] index)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.GetValueFromMember(Object exportingPart, MemberInfo exportingMember, Type importingSiteElementType, Type exportedValueType)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.<>c__DisplayClass15_0.b__0()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.GetValueForImportElement(RuntimePartLifecycleTracker importingPartTracker, RuntimeImport import, RuntimeExport export, Func`3 lazyFactory) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.GetValueForImportSite(RuntimePartLifecycleTracker importingPartTracker, RuntimeImport import) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.RuntimePartLifecycleTracker.<CreateValue>b__11_0(RuntimeImport import) at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.RuntimePartLifecycleTracker.CreateValue() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.Create() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.MoveNext(PartLifecycleState nextState) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.MoveToState(PartLifecycleState requiredState) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.GetValueReadyToExpose() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.<>c__DisplayClass15_0.<GetExportedValueHelper>b__0() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.DelegateServices.<>c__DisplayClass2_0`1.b__0()
at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue() at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
at System.Lazy`1.get_Value() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Debug.LaunchProfilesDebugLaunchProvider.GetLaunchTargetsProvider(ILaunchProfile profile) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Debug.LaunchProfilesDebugLaunchProvider.<CanBeStartupProjectAsync>d__8.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Debug.StartupProjectRegistrar.<IsDebuggableAsync>d__14.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Debug.StartupProjectRegistrar.<<OnProjectChangedAsync>b__13_0>d.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.CommonProjectSystemTools.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<<LoadedProjectAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.DataReceivingBlockSlim`1.d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.CommonProjectSystemTools.Rethrow(Exception ex)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ProjectErrorReporting.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.b__0()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ExceptionFilter.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.g__Action|0()
at GuardMethodClass.GuardMethod(Func`1 , Func`2 , Func`2 )<---

===================

'''

Comment: Have you submitted this to Microsoft?

Comment: I did in one Developer Community Forum, but not sure If I was using the right channel to report. Would you advise the best channel?

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/exception-thrown-at-target-of-invocation-during-st/1397791

Comment: I noticed another problem, I am not able to run / debug the application. An error message is displayed " An Exception has been thrown by the target of invocation"

Comment: Thanks Hans. I will check it out. By the way, the link shared is exactly another issue I am facing.

Answer (score 2):

[The link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/exception-thrown-at-target-of-invocation-during-st/1397791) provided by Hans Passant in the comments solved my issue.

In summary, I had to remove LiveShare from the installation.

This is done by running the Visual Studio Installer
-> Option Modify
-> Disable the Live Share Component.

Comment: Hi @Ricardo, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)